# Video drivers problem

Tags: ati

I am not getting satisfactory video output after installing Ubuntu 11.10.
I have a 1GB ATI Raedon graphics card but there doesnt seem to be drivers for that.
System information shows:
driver Unknown
experience Standard

Answer (score 0):

How about:

install linux headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

install driver

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

configure xorg

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Then reboot.

Per:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1965537

Comment: Sorry...but the solution u gave didn't work
Terminal msg:
E: unable to locate package amdccle

Comment: @user58312 that's `amdcccle` with 3 c's